# downgrade libsqlite3

Tags: apt, package-management

I get some errors which hint to libsqlite3. Therefore I want to downgrade libsqlite3 on Ubunutu 14.04

```
root:/usr/src# dpkg -l | grep sqlite
ii  libqt4-sql-sqlite:i386                     4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1    i386         Qt 4 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libsqlite3-0:i386                          3.8.2-1ubuntu2                             i386         SQLite 3 shared library
ii  libsqlite3-dev:i386                        3.8.2-1ubuntu2                             i386         SQLite 3 development files
```

aptitude versions doesn't show any available versions:

```
root:/usr/src# aptitude versions  libsqlite3-0:i386
Paket libsqlite3-0:
i   3.8.2-1ubuntu2                                                                trusty                                                     500
```

Google recommended the following which didn’t work:

```
root:/usr/src# aptitude install libsqlite3-0=3.7.13-1
```

1) What can I improve?

2) Is there an older (or newer) version for trustly available?